# Questão interessante sobre herança e polimorfismo

Tags: java, herança, polimorfismo

Achei interessante esta questão de um concurso público:

Classe A

```
public class ClasseA {

 public int metodoX(){
   return 10
 }
 public int metodoX(int n){
   return metodoX() + n
 } 
}
```

Classe B

```
public class ClasseB extends ClasseA{

  public int metodoX(){
    return 100
  }
  public int metodoX(int n){
    return metodoX() * n
  }
  public int metodoX(int m, int n){
    return metodoX(m) + metodoX()
  }
}
```

Principal

```
public class Principal {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClasseA obj1 = new ClasseA()
    ClasseA obj2 = new ClasseB()
    ClasseB obj3 = new ClasseB()
    int r = obj1.metodoX() + obj2.metodoX() + obj2.metodoX(5) + 
    obj3.metodoX(10, 100);
    System.out.println(r)
    }
 }
```

O resultado apresentado foi 1710. Confesso que fiquei confuso e gostaria que algum colega me explicasse com detalhes o desenvolvimento deste algoritmo.

Comment: Se poderia explicar aonde foi a confusão!

Comment: Você que esqueceu de colocar a maioria dos ponto-e-vírgulas ou foi o pessoal que fez o concurso que os essqueceu?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Estava assim, só copiei o colei.

Comment: Hahaha, então a resposta correta seria "*erro de compilação*" e você poderia entrar com um recurso para anular a questão. Se você considerar que os ponto-e-vírgulas faltantes seriam adicionados, aí sim daria 1710 e as respostas abaixo já explicam o porquê.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic  O instanciamento "ClasseA obj2 = new ClasseB()", porque será que fizeram assim?

Comment: @DenisCaixeta Lembre-se que `ClasseB` herda de `ClasseA`, então uma variável do tipo `ClasseA` pode guardar um objeto do tipo `ClasseB`. Os métodos que podem ser chamados são os do tipo da variável (`ClasseA`), mas os métodos que são de fato chamados são os do objeto nela guardado (`ClasseB`). Ou seja, `obj2.metodoX(1, 2)` é erro de compilação, mas `obj2.metodoX()` chama o método `metodoX()` da `ClasseB`.

Comment: Ok, entendi. Obrigado.

Comment: @DenisCaixeta nesse caso em especifico `ClasseA` na instância da variável `obj2` é o **tipo**, mas, sua instância é da `ClasseB` que herdou o comportamento da `ClasseA`, apesar que nesse o comportamento esperado é da `ClasseB` porque reescreveu os métodos `metodoX()` e `metodoX(int n)`. O método contido na ClasseB: `metodoX(int m, int n)` não faz parte do tipo da `ClasseA`, por isso nem aparece. É um boa pergunta muitos que trabalham com **POO** não sabe disso, e foi muito legal postar sua duvida, parabéns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para entender o resultado é preciso desmembrar o cálculo abaixo em quatro partes.

```
int r = obj1.metodoX() + obj2.metodoX() + obj2.metodoX(5) + 
obj3.metodoX(10, 100);
```

1ª Parte: `obj1.metodoX()`

O **obj1** corresponde à classe **ClasseA**. A execução do ***metodoX()*** retorna o valor **10**.

2ª Parte: `obj2.metodoX()`

O **obj2** corresponde à **ClasseB**. Apesar do **obj2** herdar os métodos da **ClasseA**, a execução do ***metodoX()*** é o da **ClasseB**, de modo que o valor retornado é **100**.

3ª Parte: `obj2.metodoX(5)`

Esta chamada executa o ***metodoX(int n)*** da **ClasseB**, que por sua vez retorna o resultado da expressão `metodoX() + n`. O ***metodoX()*** chamado nessa expressão é o da **ClasseB**, que retorna o valor 100, ou seja, o resultado desta execução é `100 * 5` que é **500**.

4 ª Parte: `obj3.metodoX(10, 100)`

Na chamada acima é executado outro método da **ClasseB** que faz chamadas aos métodos da própria **ClasseB**, retornando o valor ***1100***.

Dessa forma, o resultado final é **10 + 100 + 500 + 1100 = 1710**.

Sobre a questão da herança, note que existem métodos da **ClasseA** com o mesmo nome na **ClasseB**.
Neste exemplo encontrado por você, a **ClasseB** herda os métodos da **ClasseA**, porém os métodos da **ClasseA** não foram utilizados na **classeB**. Por esta razão, todas as chamadas na **ClasseB** fazem referência aos próprios métodos e não aos da classe pai.

Para que, na **classeB** fosse realizada uma chamada a um método "***metodoX()***" da **ClasseA**, a chamada deveria ser precedida do ponteiro **super**.

Um breve exemplo seria:

```
public classe ClasseB extends ClasseA {
   public int metodoX(){
      return 100
   }

   public int metodoX(int n){
      return super.metodoX() * n
   }

   public int metodoX(int m, int n){
      return super.metodoX(m) + metodoX()
   }
}
```

Com o exemplo acima, a herança seria efetivamente utilizada no código, de modo que o resultado final seria diferente.

Com relação à sobrecarga, esta foi utilizada quando as classes foram implementadas com métodos de mesmo nome, porém com assinaturas diferentes.

Comment: A dúvida estava mesmo sobre a  herança, o exemplo que deu é muito bom.

Answer (score 2):

A explicação é o seguinte:

Existe um conceito na programação chamado de **Sobrecarga de métodos**, onde você cria métodos com o mesmo nome, porém com assinaturas diferentes. **Variando o número de parâmetros** e ou **tipo de parâmetros**.

Note os métodos da ClasseA, são métodos com o mesmo nome **metodoX** porém com parâmetros diferentes. Um não recebe parâmetros **metodoX()** e o outro recebe parâmetro do tipo int **metodoX(int n)**.

```
public class ClasseA {

 public int metodoX(){ //assinatura sem parâmetros
   return 10
 }
 public int metodoX(int n){ //assinatura com parâmetro tipo int
   return metodoX() + n
 } 
}
```

Agora vamos explicar o resultado:

```
int r = obj1.metodoX() + obj2.metodoX() + obj2.metodoX(5) + obj3.metodoX(10, 100);
int r = 10 + 100 + (100 * 5) + ((100 * 10) + 100);
int r = 110 + 500 + 1100;
int r = 1710
```

Veja a implementação das classes com comentários.

```
public class ClasseA {

 public int metodoX(){
   return 10
 }
 public int metodoX(int n){
   // return 10 + n
   return metodoX() + n
 } 
}

public class ClasseB extends ClasseA{

  public int metodoX(){
    return 100
  }
  public int metodoX(int n){
    // return 100 * n
    return metodoX() * n
  }
  public int metodoX(int m, int n){
    // return (100 * m) + 100
    return metodoX(m) + metodoX()
  }
}
```

Agora se sobrecarga de métodos é um tipo de polimorfismo é outra conversa. 
http://www.guj.com.br/t/sobrecarga-e-um-exemplo-de-polimorfismo/37028

Esse link tem uma discussão bacana a respeito.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi a operação em r é:

```
int r = 10 + 100 + 500 + 1100;
```

por que:
O "obj1.metodoX()" é o primeiro método da classe a, onde retorna 10;

O "obj2.metodoX()" é o primeiro método da classe b, onde retorna 100;

Já o "obj2.metodoX(5)" é o segundo método da classe b, onde é pego o argumento n=5, vezes o primeiro método da classe b que retorna 100, isso da 500;

Por ultimo "obj3.metodoX(10, 100)" é o terceiro método da classe b, onde é pego o primeiro argumento m=10, chama-se o segundo método da classe b, passando o argumento 10 (já explico), onde retorna 1000, é somado com o resultado do primeiro método da classe b que é 100, resultado 1100, nesse caso é ignorado o segunda argumento o "n" pois não tem aplicação na terceira função, como foi passado o argumento "m" na terceira função, ele se torna o "n" na segunda, métodos em java recebem o parâmetro e guardão na variável o método é chamado da seguinte forma metodoX(10);

Espero ter ajudado a entender.